# nginx redirect to index.html file

Tags: nginx

I have just started using `nginx` and would like to know how can I point:

```
https://xxx.yyy.zzz/abc/test/
```

to

```
https://xxx.yyy.zzz/abc/test/index.html
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does your current configuration look like?

Comment: i just copied the default configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
location /abc/test {
     root /local/path/to/html;
     index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: This popup on browser

404 Not Found

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)